# Where main code should be located ?(C++/CLI Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have began making a project in Visual Studio 2012 C++/CLI . 
But I have some questions about correct formatting and placing. 
Firstly, where should be main code located ? Creating GUI means that it will be a lot of events(like button clicks, text inputs and so on ) . But is it correct to place code of events in header file ?
My .cpp file looks like that

```
#include "MyForm.h"


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MultiLevelList::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

}
```

All events are in MyForm.h .

Also events are private , so I haven't possibility to use them in separate .cpp file.

What is correct style of writting ?
Thx in advance .

Comment: Please learn to tag your questions appropriately. C++ and C++/CLI are not the same thing.

Comment: There is also MyForm.cpp file, which currently has only `#include "MyForm.h"` line. This is the place for `MyForm` class implementation. Move functions to it according to general C++ rules.